# jQuery - Slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to get a simple slider working... nothing is happening. I do this code below in JSFiddle (jquery 1.7.2, jQueryUI 1.8.1) and it works.. however... in web page.. it does not. It is simple a slider without its handle.

I go into console and there is no (error) message...

Help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <title>Sin título 1</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( ".slider" ).slider({
           animate: true,
               range: "min",
               value: 50,
               min: 0,
               max: 100,
               step: 1,
               slide: function( event, ui ) {
                   $("#slider-result").html( ui.value );
               }
               });</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{
background: #CECECE !important;
padding:10px;
}

/*the slider background*/
.slider {
width:230px;
height:10px;
background: #737373;
position:relative;
margin:0;
padding:0 10px;
}

/*Style for the slider button*/
.ui-slider-handle {
width:16px;
height:16px;
position:absolute;
top:-3px;
margin-left:-12px;
z-index:200;
background:#404040;
    outline:none;
}
/*This is the fill bar colour*/
.ui-widget-header {
background:#ABABAB;
height:8px;
left:1px;
top:1px;
position:absolute;
}
​
-->
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="slider"></div>
<div id="slider-result">50</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's a working fiddle apparently. http://jsfiddle.net/D45mp/

Comment: Can it be because you are missing document.ready function

Answer (score 3):

Just Add your script at the end of the document before `</body></html>` of course, like this

```
<html>
<body>
 // Divs spans and other stuff

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".slider").slider({
                animate: true,
                range: "min",
                value: 50,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                step: 1,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
                }
            });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or

write that inside a `document.ready()` script block

Comment: Why should the script tag come inside body , shouldn't it be inside the head?

Comment: Now explain to me why that worked... please... I have no idea why. :-)

Comment: <head> make script execute before the element render out, that's why we need document.ready for that. And there is an article about do not put script in head be cause it will slow you down =))

Comment: @weka jsfiddle auto matic put your javascript in onload event