# JQuery Slider value returns [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, slider

I'm trying to get the initial value of a slider once loaded. It appears that in IE9 `$('#slideramount').slider('option','value')`  returns [object object] randomly instead of the actual value.

I'm using jquery 1.8.0, and jquery-ui 1.9.1

Code:

```
<div id="slideramount" class="slider"></div>

$("#slideramount").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    step: 50,
    value: 1000,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        //do stuff
    }
});

//sometimes returns the value, other times returns [object object]
console.log($('#slideramount').slider('option','value'));
```

It only seems to be happening in IE9 like 50% of the time. Chome/FF/IE10 work fine.

I'm testing IE9 by running IE10 in IE9 Browser/Document mode, not sure if that would be fudging up the results?

It looks like the slider doesn't load properly when it return [object object] but I'm not sure why. I've checked to make sure jqueryui is loaded, and such. I'm running out of ideas.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed around the code so that it creates the sliders on `$(document).ready()` then try and retrieve the value `console.log($("#slideramount").slider("value"));` on `$(window).load()`.

When it fails I get a **Cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization** so it's like the slider doesn't create itself properly. Not sure why, but it still only fails sometimes in IE9.

**FIXED:**

So I've finally managed to fix it (it was pretty silly).

I had the javascript in it's own file, so the HTML looked like this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/sliders.js"></script>

<div id="slideramount" class="slider></div>
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896207/jquery-slider-not-working) to "Just Add your script at the end of the document" so I moved the script under all the relevant HTML, and voila the sliders would always load. I can't believe I didn't think of that before...

There must've been js in the script file that was referencing some DOM elements before they were loaded, even though I was loading the sliders on `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: why don't you use the value method `var selection = $( "#slideramount" ).slider( "value" );`

Comment: I tried that in the beginning, same result. then I started looking around, and everyone was using ('option','value') so I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the slider value from the Slider itself and you are not using an `<input>` to store its' value as you slide.

The logic is:

- Create slider from DIV
- As you slide the slider, jQuery UI calculates the value and gives it to an `<input>`
- You need to check the value in the `<input>` rather than the slider `<div>`

According to the docs your code should look like this:

**HTML**

```
<p>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="a_slider"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// instantiate the slider widget to the <div> and set configuration options
$("#a_slider").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    step: 50,
    value: 1000, // this is an option so it sets the position of the slider before it gets displayed on-screen
    slide: function (event, ui) {

        // upon sliding store the value
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );

        // fire off the console every time a slide is made
        console.log($( "#amount" ).val());

        // OR you can go through the widget and have it tell you the value
        console.log($( "#a_slider" ).slider( "value" ));
    }
});

// Use it here to get the value after loading the widget
// ask the instantiated slider widget to tell you it's current value
alert($( "#a_slider" ).slider( "value" ));
```

Comment: doesn't this `alert($( "#a_slider" ).slider( "value" ));` get the value of the `<div>`? Or does it grab the `<input>` value? Because it's that line that's returning the object.

Comment: `"value"` is a method within the slider widget which asks the widget to return the current value of that slider. http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value

Comment: I don't see how adding an `<input>` would then make `alert($( "#a_slider" ).slider( "value" ));` work, unless it's trying to find the `<input>` value.

Also still doesn't explain why it works 50% of the time.